# Dim Complete Background When a Fragment is opened in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, background

How to dim complete background when a fragment is opened likewise when a DialogFragment is created.

Rightnow I am able to dim the background of only the app window using a view with match_parent as height and width. But using it ***does not dim the background of the status bar*** which happens with the DialogFragment.

I want to dim complete background including apps window and the status bar when the fragment is created or opened.

Right now this happens with the DialogFragment. But I have to use only Fragment.

Comment: Have you tried, 
getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
?

Comment: Yes i tried it in fragment onCreateView but did not work.

Comment: @kanudo How did you implement this?

Comment: @ashwinmahajan am animating the status and navigation bar color. It feels hacky but it does the work

Answer (score 1):

That's what I did
I took a relative layout with height and width match_parent, apart from my fragment's main layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_transition"/>
```

This is my background_transition file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="00FFFFFF" />
<item android:drawable="#B3FFFFFF" />
</transition>
```

Then in order to dim the background, create TransitionDrawable object like this in your fragment

```
 private TransitionDrawable transition;
```

and then call

```
transition.startTransition(300);
```

to dim the background, and

```
transition.reverseTransition(300);
```

to go back to normal background.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not what I require friend, this is similar to what I am right now with.

Comment: You can dim the status bar separately, refer to https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried Nuzha's version and my app crashed as well.

I did find two possible solutions.

**1) If you use the following code it will make the back-fragment whiter, not dimmed:**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            view.alpha = 0.2F
        }
```

Note:
Depending on the value you set, the closer the Float is to 0, the more transparent-white the background will be (only works with 23+)

**2) If you would like the back-fragment to be dimmed (dark)**

First, you can create a color in your resources folder and make it a bit transparent. I for one used the following one for a darker effect: #7E000000

Next, in the onViewCreated() method, create a variable of the color and add it as a ColorDrawable to the view's foreground.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
           val color: Int = R.color.black_transparent
           view.foreground = ColorDrawable(resources.getColor(color, resources.newTheme()))
```

Note
Make sure to disable any buttons that might be visible in the back-fragment, otherwise, if the user presses it, the app will crash

```
     buttonRegisterEvent.isEnabled = false
```

As a final step, if you want the user to navigate back to the former fragment, make sure to remove the foreground color and enable any buttons that you might have disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fragmentParentLayout.getForeground().setAlpha(215);
```

Comment: Crashes my application in onCreateView()